# MS Word 2013 Add-in not capture delete key

Tags: ms-word

I am developing add-in for MS-Word 2013. I needed to capture delete keypress event when user delete something in Word. I am unable to capture it. Can anyone help to me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard-Hook does not works in MS-Word 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971020/keyboard-hook-does-not-works-in-ms-word-2013), please update you original question.

Comment: Please add the information requested in the comment on your previous question